# Do songs played in quick play benefit the crew?

Tags: rock-band-4, rock-band-rivals

I just joined a crew in Rock Band Rivals and wanted to know if playing songs in quick play benefits our crews overall level or adds to our xp.

Does playing in quick play benefit my crew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does benefit the crew. In fact:

> No matter what feature you’re playing (Quickplay, Rockudrama, or Shows), you’ll be contributing to your Crew’s progress. [Source: Harmonix](http://www.harmonixmusic.com/blog/whats-coming-in-october-rock-band-rivals-features-revealed/)